# Using a variable for value inside jQuery attribute-equals-value selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I have a `div` with an attribute of "foldername" which can something like "shoes, "dresses," etc . The div looks like this:

```
<div id='folder_template' class="openclosed_folder_icon subfolder" foldername="shoes">
    <img class="folder_icon" src="images/folder_closed.png"  />
    <div class="folder_label">name</div> 
</div>
```

I want to search for the div that has a particular value for foldername and change the image in it from "folder_closed.png" to "folder_open.png," so the graphic looks like an open folder instead of a closed folder. So I have the code:

```
$("div[foldername=g.currentGallery]").attr('src','images/folder_open.png');
```

where g.currentGallery is a variable holding the gallery name, e.g., "shoes," that I want to change.
But this line gives me the error:

> Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>   div[foldername=g.currentGallery]

But it will take:

```
$("div[foldername='shoes']").attr('src','images/folder_open.png');
```

Why can't I use a variable here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
$('div[foldername="' + g.currentGallery.replace(/"/g, '\\"') + '"]').attr(/* whatever */);
```

Example if we have:

```
var g = { currentGallery: 'shoes["1"]' };
```

Then the selector expression becomes:

```
div[foldername="shoes[\"1\"]"]
```

Comment: This will allow any char, even `]`: `..foldername='" + g.currentGallery + "']...` ... See: http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/k0976349/ @salmanA?

Comment: @PeterKA: yes, when `]` is present in attribute value then quotes become necessary. Revised the answer.

Comment: +1 for quote escaping in the string. Never hurts to always quote anyway. :)

Comment: My code doesn't have any quotes to escape so the simplified solution was

 `$('div[foldername="' + g.currentGallery + '"]').find('img').attr('src','images/folder_open.png');` 

Thanks